# create responsive Shaped

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm looking to create a responsive trapezoid shape  like this image:

[image]

What is the **best way** to build something like this in HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 3):

One CSS approach to achieve the effect you're looking to re-create is to use:

- an `::after` pseudo-element
- with a `skew` **CSS Transform** applied

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(253, 114, 76);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(190, 60, 28, 0.7);
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: rgb(253, 114, 76);
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  transform: skewY(-3deg) translateY(-8px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot 
but is it responsive?

Comment: Yes, you can straightforwardly give this element responsive `width`, `height`, `padding` and `margin` using `%` and `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` & `vmax` units.

Answer (score -1):

The best way in my opinion would be to just use a vector image.
I'm thinking something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Trapezium</title>

  <style>
    img {
      width: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="trapez.svg">
</body>

</html>
```

You can find the SVG (Vector) I used here: https://easyupload.io/fy7y7i

Have a great day!